# Add a rectangle(container) at the bottom of last page .rdlc

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I am creating an invoice report in .rdlc, i want to add some text box controls at the bottom of the last page.

I have a table into the body of the report which contains the rows which can expand depending on the description column.

I tried to add the rectangle as a container in the footer of the report(with all text boxes) and set the footer to display only on the last page, but this approach leave empty space(of the size of footer) in the previous pages this is a problem if the invoice contains more pages.

This [Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864462/set-a-textbox-at-the-bottom-part-of-rdlc-report) doesn't work for me as i have rows with number of lines not fix.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried hiding the rectangle on the other pages? Even if it's empty, the rectangle will "save" the space given to it in the designer. But if the rectangle is hidden, I think it will give up that space.